# VETiledLayer in ArcGIS JavaScript API v4?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm a first-time arcgis js user, and I'm trying to figure out how to use bing maps (or google maps) with it. So far I found out that with v3 you used `VETiledLayer` – however that seems to be gone in v4.

**what's the way to do this in the latest version?**